# How do I compare two tables that contain Null values

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to compare two tables from different databases.
I am aware that there are different ways of doing this and the one below may not be the most obvious but there are several things that need to be taken into consideration which would be to cumbersome to discuss here.

The way I'd like to have it done is by concatenating fields and compare the results

```
SELECT x.* 
FROM     ( SELECT * 
           FROM tblA 'C:\F1\db.mdb'
         ) x      
LEFT JOIN 
        ( SELECT * 
          FROM tblA IN 'C:\F2\db.mdb'
         ) y 
ON (x.fldId = y.fldId) 
AND (x.fldInstrNr = y.fldInstrNr) 
AND (x.fldCode = y.fldCode) 
AND (x.fldQty = y.fldQty) 
AND (x.fldUnit = y.fldUnit) 
AND (x.fldType = y.fldType) 
WHERE (
        ( x.ID & ';' & x.fldId & ';' & x.fldInstrNr & ';' & x.fldCode & ';' & x.fldQty  & ';' & x.fldUnit & ';' & x.fldType & ';' & x.zsfldDemo) <> 
        ( y.ID & ';' & y.fldId & ';' & y.fldInstrNr & ';' & y.fldCode & ';' & y.fldQty & ';' & y.fldUnit & ';' & y.fldType & ';' & y.zsfldDemo))
```

This works, except when there are null-values in fields.
records with null-values will end up in the result although the record in both database are equal

Is there a way to solve this, and preferably in a way more or less like the above?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *Nz* if not too many records:

```sql
ON (Nz(x.fldId) = Nz(y.fldId)) 
AND (Nz(x.fldInstrNr) = Nz(y.fldInstrNr)) 
AND (Nz(x.fldCode) = Nz(y.fldCode)) 
AND (Nz(x.fldQty) = Nz(y.fldQty)) 
AND (Nz(x.fldUnit) = Nz(y.fldUnit)) 
AND (Nz(x.fldType) = Nz(y.fldType))
```

Comment: There are over 400000 records. I tried your suggestion but after half an hour I aborted the query...

Comment: Then use your original code and filter the result for _Null_ values.